# Fork a child process,runs permanently in the background and do work In c

Tags: c, pipe, fork, parent

I want to fork a child process that runs permanently in the background, and parent will prompt the user to enter a line of text. Then display the number of lines entered by the user in child process.

how to do it??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    pid_t pid;
    int mypipe[2];
    int ret;
    char str[5000];
    char buff[2000];
    int status = 0;    
    int lines  = 1; 
    int c = 0;
    int line[1000];
    ret = pipe(mypipe); 

    if (ret == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        read(mypipe[0],line,50);
        printf("Child count line : %d\n", line[0]);
    }
    else 
    {
        //in parent process
        printf("In Parent Process\n");
        printf("Enter somthing: \n");

        while ((c =getchar())!= '*'){
           if (c == '\n'){
          lines++; 
        }
        line[0] = lines;
        write(mypipe[1],line,sizeof(int));
        }
        wait(&status);
    }
}
```

The ideal output should look like this:

```
ds
Child count line : 1
sd
Child count line : 2
sd
Child count line : 3
sd
Child count line : 4
```

Comment: Have a `while(1)` loop in both parent and child process? It's not entirely clear what your difficulty is in extending your current code.

Comment: what is the o/p you are getting?

Comment: Im getting only one time of counting.
 ds
Child count line : 1
sd
sd
sd